# mod_rewrite .htaccess on AJAX calls throwing errors

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, concrete5

I'm developing a new site for a church.
The old domain is: **chippingcampdenbaptistchurch.org.uk**
The new domain is: **campdenbaptist.org.uk**

The campdenbaptist.org.uk domain is an addon domain to a Linux shared server.
Inside it's folder it has the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^(dev(/.*)?|www\.chippingcampdenbaptistchurch\.org\.uk)$ http://www.chippingcampdenbaptistchurch.org.uk/ [R,L]
```

Basically, if the user is asking for JUST campdenbaptist.org.uk then they will get sent to the old site (living on a different server at www.chippingcampdenbaptistchurch.org.uk). BUT if they are asking for campdenbaptist.org.uk/dev - then they are sent into the /dev folder where the new site lives.

It runs on Concrete5 (http://www.concrete5.org/) and the .htaccess inside this /dev folder looks like this:

```
SetEnv TZ Europe/London

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

#=============WWW. REDIRECT===========#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/dev/$1 [R=301,L]

#=============C5 REDIRECT===========#
RewriteBase /dev/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

It basically checks to see if the www. is there (and if not, append it)
And deals with the Pretty URLs in the 'C5 redirect' block.

The issue I'm having is that sometimes the server seems to throw errors (redirects to old site) for AJAX calls, such as the following two:

```
http://www.campdenbaptist.org.uk/dev/tools/blocks/booking_form/snag_dates.php?1=1&date=03/16/2013&page=272
```

(if you change 1=1 in the first part of the query string to something like a=1 it seems fine?!)
- or

```
http://www.campdenbaptist.org.uk/dev/tools/required/files/importers/remote?_returntype=text&fIDW&task=update_file&url_upload_1=http%3A%2F%2Ffeatherfiles.aviary.com%2F2012-11-26%2F1d6b111bd5684978a293e193828a181a.jpg&ccm_token53952089%3A5ec7e1b4c88c7e62ba9f5da66b36cef0
```

Any ideas? It seems to be that if you remove the query strings from both of the above calls the error doesn't occur.
Thanks very much!

Comment: are there any header redirects inside of snag_dates.php or any php files it may include? Try commenting out or deleting your htaccess files and see if it still behaves this way to confirm if htaccess is indeed the culprit. Clear your browser cache first to be sure its not storing redirects as they sometimes do.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, tried it all but to no avail.
Something really odd here. If you go to:
`http://www.campdenbaptist.org.uk/dev/tools/blocks/booking_form/snag_dates.php?1=1&date=03/16/2013&page=272`

or 

`http://www.campdenbaptist.org.uk/dev/tools/blocks/booking_form/snag_dates.php?a=1&date=03/16/2013&page=272`

the outcome varies between a forbidden and a return for just changing 1=1 to a=1 - how odd!
(I've got rid of the htaccess redirecting to the old site address, it's now just an index.php with header("Location: chippingcampdenbaptistchurch.org.uk") so can see the error pages.

Comment: I tried it with several query strings and its not just 1=1, it seemed to be any (numeric key)=(numeric value). I tried again just now and for a minute or two the 1=1 was not redirecting (200 OK) but then it just started its throwing 403 so I'm guessing youre still currently testing?

Comment: Hi there, yeah sorry I got fed up of it redirecting so instead of htaccess redirect to old site it's now just an index.php file with a header("Location:...") redirect, so we can see errors instead.
See comment i placed below [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572184/mod-rewrite-htaccess-on-ajax-calls-throwing-errors#comment18599754_13573149) for more developments!

Comment: And similarly, with or without the full stop on the end of this seems to throw a 403 or a 200 respectively!
`http://www.campdenbaptist.org.uk/dev/index.php/tools/required/files/importers/remote?_returntype=text&fIDW&task=update_file&url_upload_1=http%3A%2F%2Ffeatherfiles.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annoyingly, it was a mod_sec error caused by the hosting provider. 1=1 is now fixed, and they're currently working on the .aviary.com problem. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a hard coded redirect in one of your php files that is checking for 1 in the query string or perhaps a config var for site address that needs changing.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the case, if you take the last ajax call I originally posted and try it, it shows a 403 forbidden. If you delete up till just before the full stop in featherfiles.aviary.com in the querystring, it's ok??

`http://www.campdenbaptist.org.uk/dev/tools/required/files/importers/remote?_returntype=text&fIDW&task=update_file&url_upload_1=http%3A%2F%2Ffeatherfiles` - works! but the full query string with . doesn't seem to. Similary changing 1=1 to a=1 in the first example, makes it work?

Comment: so if the text 'chippingcampdenbaptistchurch.org.uk' doesn't appear anywhere in your codebase, then I guess it isn't problem. The next thing to look at is caching. What caching do you in place?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a .htaccess issue actually by the looks of things. Disabled pretty URLs (there is no caching in place btw) and here's a direct link to index.php file which then processes the remainder of the /query/string/like/this

`http://www.campdenbaptist.org.uk/dev/index.php/tools/blocks/booking_form/snag_dates.php?1=1&date=03/16/2013&page=272`

And that throws an error. Must be a PHP issue throwing a forbidden error when it's 1=1 but not a=1? or a=2? Very odd...